# Recovering Mojibaked Files

Tags: unicode, corruption

I have recently been encountering several broken files whose contents got thoroughly baked in conversions between UTF-8 and ISO-Latin-1. How can I repair these files?

The process that created the broken text in question went like this:

1. The original text, "ó", was saved as UTF-8 (`0xC3B3`).
2. The encoded bytes (`0xC3` and `0xB3`) were interpreted as ISO-Latin-1 characters, "Ã" and "³".
3. These characters were saved as their UTF-8 representations (`0xC383` and `0xC2B3`).

The file now contains the bytes `C3 83 C2 B3`. From this, I need to reconstruct the original string, "ó".

How can I repair files with this (or similar) types of corruption?

Comment: BTW: You have C2 B2 instead of B3. I think that's a typo in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iconv -f utf8 -t latin1` should fix it.

For example:

```
echo 'C3 83 C2 B3' | xxd -p -r ; echo                             # ³ is C2 B3; suspect typo in your question
Ã³                                                                # confirms xxd -p -r works
echo 'C3 83 C2 B3' | xxd -p -r | iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 ; echo
ó                                                                 # got the ó back
```

Basically, the iconv undoes the Latin1->UTF8 conversion, leaving you with the "latin1" you had before (which you then treat as UTF8).